Websocket in OpenAI streaming not working on M1 Pro MacBook
I have created an app with react and fastapi and I wanted to include streaming in it to make it better and more user friendly.
A person working with me on the project implemented a solution with websockets it on windows and it's working but on my macbook m1 pro it's not. The thing is that everything works fine : the connection with websocket is working, the streaming from fastapi is good but it seems that the messages are not received until the last one, ie when the request is completed (see code).
Does anyone know how it can be doing that ?
Here is the code :
FRONTEND
in shared > sockets > socket.js
import { ENDPOINTS,SOCKET_BASE_URL } from '../constants/urls';

const URL = ENDPOINTS.SOCKET_URL;

export const connectSocket = (id)=>{
  return  new WebSocket(`${SOCKET_BASE_URL.SOCKET_BASE_URL}${URL}?uniqueId=${id}`)
}

in my index.js file (I just show you the part of code related to socket) :
  const [ws,setWs] = useState();
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state?.auth);
  useEffect(() => {
   
   if(userInfo && !ws){
    const ws =connectSocket(userInfo.unique_id)
    setWs(ws);

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
   
      if(data.isRewrite){
        config.mainOutput=""
        config.mainOutputHandler(
          config.mainOutput
        )
      } else {
        config.mainOutput +=data.data
        config.mainOutputHandler(
          config.mainOutput
        )
        const offsetBottom = divRef.current?.offsetTop + divRef.current?.offsetHeight;
        window.scrollTo({ top: offsetBottom })
      }
    };
   }
  }, [userInfo]);

And on BACKEND :
in utils.webSocketManager :
from fastapi import  WebSocket
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: list[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_text(message)

    async def broadcast(self, message: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(message)

in content_generation.py (in router folder) :
@router.post("/generate/", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def generation_function(
    content: ContentSchema,
    to_rewrite: Union[bool, None] = False,
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
    user: User = Depends(config.get_current_user),
):
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
        
        ...
        
        role_prompt = prompt_generator.ROLE_POST.format(VARIABLES
            ),
            company=prompt_generator.company_or_default(VARIABLES
            ),
        )
        user_prompt = prompt_generator.CONTENT_PROMPT.format(
            VARIABLES
        )

        if(len(manager.active_connections)>0):
             webSocket =  next(p for p in manager.active_connections if p.query_params.get('uniqueId') == user.unique_id)
        else:
            webSocket = None

        messages = [
            {"role": "system", "content": role_prompt},
            {"role": "user", "content": user_prompt},
        ]

        if to_rewrite:
            messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": content.content})
            messages.append(
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": "Text",
                }
            )
            resp = {
                "data": "",
                "isRewrite": to_rewrite
            }
            if(webSocket is not None):
                await manager.send_personal_message(json.dumps(resp), webSocket)

        openai.organization = user.openai_organization
        openai.api_key = decrypt_api_key(user.openai_api_key)
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-4o", 
            messages=messages,
            stream=True,
            stream_options= {"include_usage": True}
        )

        
        data = []
        usage=None
        for chunk in response:
            if len(chunk.choices)>0:
                if chunk.choices[0].delta is not None:
                    if 'content' in  chunk.choices[0].delta.keys():
                        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
                            # print(chunk.choices[0].delta.content, end="")

                            if webSocket is not None:
                                    resp = {
                                        "data":chunk.choices[0].delta.content,
                                        "isRewrite" : False
                                    }
                                    await manager.send_personal_message(json.dumps(resp), webSocket)
                            data.append(chunk.choices[0].delta.content)
            else:
                usage = chunk.usage

        data = ''.join(data)

        return {
            "status":status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "data": data
        }
    
    # except Exception as e:
    #     print(str(e))
    #     raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=str(e))

Thanks in advance !!
